# Building Chrome: Unable to Rebase Cygwin

Tags: google-chrome, cygwin, rebase

In my effor to fix `CygwinDllRemappingFailure` [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/cygwin) [more details](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/CygwinDllRemappingFailure) obtained when doing

> gclient sync --force

I am using this command, to rebase Cygwin installation.

```
 ash /usr/bin/rebaseall
```

But I otain following error.

```
 /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/CORE/cygperl5_14_2.dll:
 skipped because non existent
```

I have verified perl5 package does exist on my system. In fact, In my last try, I have installed all packages that contained perl5 keyword. Landed up with no success.

Have spent significant time searching and executing commands. Have you come across this error. Any advice on this error would be much helpful.

Comment: I have the same idea with trying to run rebaseall in an attempt to resolve the fork() error. It complains about the same dll and fails to run.

Comment: @aberrant80 Consider upvoting the question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This person, who I believe is the author of that package, says you can ignore it:

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-07/msg00664.html

Ryan